# No customer_id in sales_flat_quote but forced login?

Tags: magento-1.9, quote, magento1.9.3, sales-quote

In our shop there are records in the table `sales_flat_quote` where the `customer_id` is `NULL`. If I understand correctly this is due to a customer not being logged in.

The catch is that our shop has forced login: without loggin in a customer can't enter the shop.

This issue causes several problems:

- Sometimes customers receive an error when they try to place an order.
- Sometimes when one account logs in on two different machines, two different shopping carts exist under the same account.

Does anybody have any idea as to why sometimes the `customer_id` is not recorded?

Magento version 1.9.3.7

For forcing the login we use a module. When the customer tries to place the order they One Step Checkout keeps loading and a red bar without text appears. The admin receives an email with "Payment Transaction Failed Reminder" without any more information.

Also, this problem occurs with 30-50 regular customers but not with others. This caused be to think the problem is client based, but all clients use different OS, browsers, etc.

Comment: Magento 1 or Magento 2?

Comment: Sorry, Magento version 1.9.3.7

Comment: "without loggin in a customer can't enter the shop" -> could you elaborate how this is achieved? would it be possible for me to disable javascript, or remove a popup, and enter the shop without a login?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How quotes work in Magento](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/14056/how-quotes-work-in-magento)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate at all

Comment: Your question is :"Does anybody have any idea as to why sometimes the customer_id is not recorded?" That can be rephrased as "How to quotes work in magento" In Marius' answer he says " You can have a quote when browsing the website as guest." if you're a guest, you won't have a customer_id

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate either, because the intention is not to have guest quotes. however, there is not enough context to even guess what can be going on. **How did you setup that forced login?** **Customers receive an error, what is the error?** A lot is going on that is not right. All this is pretty vague...

Comment: @7ochem I added some more information. If you have any more questions, please let me know.

Comment: @PY  I added some more information. If you have any more questions, please let me know.

Comment: This is still very unclear and not reproducible. The best advice I could give here is to hire an expert to look into your complete webshop, it's source code and it's database.